# Item level security

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have an out of the box solution where users can log there meeting minutes in a custom list. The security of the site consists of about a 100 SharePoint groups which are being used throughout the site collection with different permissions.

For the purpose of this solution we have each group belonging to one of four logical roles (Directors, Power Users, Employees (Internal) and Employees (External). There are about 50 groups that fit the role of Employees.

We want to make sure that users can access only the items if they belong to this logical role. That means that an item created by employee has to be accessible by 50 groups.

What would be the best practice to apply security in this situation since for item level security it would require that inheritance be broken at item level and 50 groups added to the permissions of that item.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with 4 folders with explicit permissions. Creating specific role items within each folder allow us to properly secure access.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a additional super group and add all employee group into this super group? So while breaking inheritance, you need to refer to this super group only.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar but used view permission control. SharePoint doe not have this out of the box but the Boost tool does a great job. Look [here](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html).

This way you can create custom view for the different groups and have them be secure.